# Adding html class attribute conditionally on hover

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

I want to add a class to table row on hover. I know I can add classes like this:

```
<tr [class.info]="isMyConditionTrue()"></tr>
```

and "info" class will be added when my condition is `true`. But how do I check if my table row is hovered? I could set some inner variable in typescript to true on `(mouseenter)` and to false on `(mouseleave)`, but it's problematic if I have alot of rows generated by `*ngFor`. I'd have to create another component for each row or store them in some hashtable. Is there a way to achieve this just by using something like `<tr #row [class.info]="row.hovered"></tr>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hover-info'
  template: `<tr [class.info]="isHovered$ | async"></tr>
})
class HoverRow { 

   _hovers$: Subject<boolean> = BehaviorSubject.create(); 
   isHovered$: Observable<boolean> = this._hovers$.last();

   @HostListener('mouseover') onMouseover = () => this._hovers$.next(true); 
   @HostListener('mouseout') onMouseout = () => this._hovers$.next(false); 

}
```

[AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AsyncPipe-class.html) is a powerful thing.

Note that [there's an open proposal](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062) for a feature that would simplify the boilerplate needed here. I doubt it'll land before release but expect it will soon thereafter.